# Running a local powershell script for all users using schtasks

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

Normally I use GPO to run scripts for all my users but I want to push out a powershell script and if certain conditions are not met, then it will create a schedule task for all users on that computer to run a local powershell script. (Needs to run with admin privs)

I am sure the solution is very simple but I just cannot get it to work.

I have tried all of the following including setting executionpolicy to unrestricted and moving where I am storing the script locally.

```
schtasks /create /f /ru "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"  /tn "MYTASK" /tr "powershell -file C:\ProgramData\script.ps1 -executionpolicy bypass" /sc onlogon

schtasks /create /f /tn "My Task Name" /ru Administrator /sc onlogon /tr "powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\ProgramData\script.ps1"
```

I have also tried a .cmd file and .bat file with the following in them and calling them with the schtasks above:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\ProgramData\script.ps1

schtasks /create /f /tn "My Task Name" /ru Administrator /sc onlogon /tr "C:\ProgramData\script.bat"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to adjust the permissions on the task file in `C:\Windows\Tasks` for other users to be able to see the task. If that doesn't help you need to provide more information about what problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ansgar. Not sure I follow what you mean. Can you give me an example please

Comment: I found this by googling:

Comment: ICACLS “%SYSTEMROOT%\Tasks\*.*” /grant <Your Windows User Name>:f

Is this what you mean and if so, how do I change the permission to all users?

Comment: Do NOT change the permissions on `%SYSTEMROOT%\Tasks\*.*`. Change the permissions on the specific tasks you want all users to see. Grant read permissions to the group "Authenticated Users".